# Large arrays in C

Tags: c, matrix, cuda, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to implement the [OSEM algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_subset_expectation_maximization) (I'm trying because I have to, not just for fun) and I have a question:

Since I'll be working with very large matrices, I want to know the maximum array size (C language) I can allocate with malloc. From what I've read it depends on your OS and Hardware: I'm working on an Intel Xeon E5530 2.40 Ghz, Red Had Enterprise 64 bits, Nvidia Quadro FX 3800.

The matrices I'll be working with, have something like these dimensions: float/double 2000x1000x20.

Given that those matrices are to be worked with CUDA C, I must allocate the matrices in 1D arrays like this:

```
float*matrix=(float*)malloc(sizeof(float)*2000*1000*20));
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Really grateful for all your answers everyone! Stackoverflow has to be the greatest forum for programming purposes!

Answer (score 6):

These are relatively small allocations - around 160 MB for float, 320 MB for double. Unless you have a lot of these matrices concurrently then there shouldn't be a problem.

The main limitation will be with CUDA, where you may be limited by the total amount of physical memory on your GPU card, but again, unless you have a significant number of these matrices then you should be OK with any current CUDA-compatible GPU card.

Comment: The Nvidia Quadro Fx 3800 has 1024 Mb. Currently im using 3 matrices and i'll write some pseudo code to ilustrate:

`float[10000][10000] * (float) double[10000][1] = float[10000][1]`

The (float) cast is there because that matrix is double to begin with. Given this case i should not have any problems right?

Thank you for your previous answer

Comment: If you don't need double precision then see if you can stick with float for all your arrays. Double precision is not supported on many GPU cards, and has poor performance even when it is supported. Using float will also help to keep your memory footprint and bandwidth requirements down too.

Comment: The problem is that i have to work with a tomosynthesis scan, and the data i get cant be changed(afaik), so i have to work with double. I dont know if i should convert that double array to float before invoking the kernel or to do what i did(casting). Anyway thanks again for taking the time to help me, since i do not belong to the programming area i am really grateful for the help you people give me

Comment: Just reduce your initial double precision data to float (on the host PC) and then pass the converted float array to your CUDA kernel.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, there largest possible buffer you can allocate on a 64bit system is 2<sup>64</sup>, which is much larger than your 2000x1000x20 array. It's also much larger than all the memory you can ever process with a computer.

On a 32bit system it's usually 2GB. (Some systems allow 3 or 4GB.) That's 2.1 * 10<sup>9</sup> bytes. The `sizeof(float)` is 4 bytes. Let's see, you've got:

2000 * 1000 * 20 = 4 * 10<sup>7</sup>

Multiplying that by the size of a float:

4 * 10<sup>7</sup> * 4 = 1.6 * 10<sup>8</sup>

Even though 1.6*10<sup>8</sup> is quite an impressive number, you could even allocate that much memory on a 32bit system.

I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some other considerations.

- Do not worry about the although big matrix sizes, unless you need multiple images that could saturate the GPU Memory.
- If you can process the images with a small set each time DO use the **AsyncAPI** to Upload / Process / Download. While computing the first result you could be uploading the next image.
- Experiment with **CudaMallocHost**, non pageable memory ie MUCH faster data transfer
- Experiment with **Pitched Memory** on the device, even if it consumes more memory provides better access performances
- Last but not least get a better card: You can get 360 cores for ~200 $ for example with a [Gtx 460](http://www.nvidia.com/object/product-geforce-gtx-460-us.html)

Answer (score -1):

The maximum size of the arrays that you can use (i.e. the maximum amount of memeory you can allocate using `malloc` in this case) is not restricted by anything in the C language itself. It depends entirely on the amount of memory you have available in the machine.

Comment: hey, while your statement is completely correct, I downvoted the answer because it's not really helpful since he already knows that `From what I've read it depends on your OS and Hardware`. This means he wants some practical advice for his case, so I upvoted Paul R, and also downvoted the one saying `don't worry about it` (very bad advice I would say).

Comment: @steabert: My interpretation was that he seems to think the actualy type and make of his processor and OS matters - which is not exactly the case here. He mentions the types of his processor and graphics hardware as well as his OS, but no mention of the amount of RAM he has.